# mysql utf8 charset not working

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I am inserting some non-ascii(specifically asian characters into mysql table column with charset utf8, but after insertion, if I retrieve it again, it shows up as ????.  I checked the db, table and column charset, they are all utf8. what's wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE `test_utf` (
  `test_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `raw_text` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`test_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



insert into test_utf (raw_text) values('黄剑');
```

Comment: Where are you displaying them?  In a terminal window?  Is your terminal set to interpret bytes as UTF-8-encoded characters?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem solved!**

I need to add `characterEncoding=UTF-8` to whatever mysql client I'm using,

for example, when I use `jdbc` I need to specify `"jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?characterEncoding=UTF-8"` in connection url.